# What do the terms fork, master, origin, push, pull mean for Git and Github?

Tags: git, github, terminology

What are the differences between the terms:

- trunk / branch / merge / check in/out (which I know from other VCS)
- fork, master, origin, push, pull, etc. (used by Git)

Comment: careful with your assumptions!  git checkout is not the same at all!

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - entire books could be dedicated to this question. Please narrow the scope significantly to something that can be addressed in an answer. Maybe focus on a single keyword pair, per question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This first thing that is important to understand about Git is that it thinks about version control very differently than Subversion or Perforce or whatever SCM you may be used to. It is often easier to learn Git by trying to forget your assumptions about how version control works and try to think about it in the Git way.

-- http://gitref.org/

Comment: gitref.org is nice, but doesn't define `fork`

Comment: Downvote from me. Answers should answer the question rather than deferring to external links.

Answer (score 4):

Read this: http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html

Comment: Downvote from me. Answers should answer the question rather than deferring to external links.

Answer (score 2):

This could have been googled. I guess that is why someone -ve repped the question. I googled "Git Glossary" and this was the first result -

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html

It explains most of what you are asking.

http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html is a great reference too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I run into this doc in its full version (hundreds of pages), so wasn't sure where to find this simple answer, but will dig into this link. Thanks again.

Comment: Downvote from me. Answers should answer the question rather than deferring to external links.

Comment: @DuncanJones - Why don't you post the entire git documentation here? These "external links" are better than any answer one can post here. Next, go down vote the OP and comment "This is googleable!"

Comment: @LordLoh. I've already downvoted the OP and voted to close. It was a bad question that begot bad answers. It should have been closed when asked.

Comment: @DuncanJones sadly you are 7 years too late! And did you choose "This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing."? Which clause of the above is the question satisfying? Too broad? Opinion? Not about Programming?